# Can't use $ in NETEXPRESS

Tags: cobol

I'm writing a COBOL program with NETEXPRESS.
I wrote $ZZZZ9.99 in detail line and it works when I use school desktop but I get an error "PICTURE string has illegal character " if I compile it with my laptop.

```
05  DL-WAGE           PIC $ZZZZ9.99     VALUE ZERO.
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?? I used the same version of NEXEXPRESS in both places.

Comment: Just a guess: you have a `CURRENCY-SIGN` directive set that is not the `$`.

Side note: try to edit a "less good" question next time instead of delete + re-ask.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I cannot use the previous question so I deleted it. And, I don't know why I cannot use $ on my laptop even I use same version of NETEXPRESS that I installed on school-desktop.

Comment: You may be using the same version but are they installed with the same options?

Comment: You should be able to set directives like this "systems-wide", possibly "project-wide" and "only for a specific file" (if NETEXPRESS editor / IDE allows this, I've only looked at some of their docs, never had the program open).
You definitely set it within the source-code, this way it would work identical in both environments.